# Retreive data from query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 6 columns where one column is Id (big int , primary), and one column CreatedDate (datetime), and it has rows more than one million.
when retrieving data from this table using the below query takes more than 1 minute.

```
select * from MyTable where CreatedDate between '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-30'
```

I used below query also, but it also takes more than 1 minute.

```
declare @minId bigint, @maxId bigint
select @minId = min(Id) from MyTable  where CreatedDate > = '2019-05-01'
select @maxId = max(id) from MyTable  where CreatedDate <= '2019-05-30'
select @minId, @maxId
select * from MyTable  where Id between @minId and @maxId
```

It has only one index (Id - primary key), and I assume adding index to CreatedDate may affect insert/update operations.

I want to join this result to another table to get some report data to display in a grid, but when executing this query time out occurs.

How can I retrieve data quickly?

Comment: I *assume* you don't have an index (or a covering index) on your table `MyTable`? What indexes do you have? Can you include the DDL for your table and it's respective indexes please?

Comment: As a side note: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @Larnu Table has one column 'Id' which is a primary key.

Comment: Clearly it doesn't, @JijuJohn, as you have the column `CreatedDate` too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create index on CreatedDate will help in retrieval while it will have some side-effect in Insert
2. Avoid selecting all columns with the '*' wildcard, unless you intend to use them all. Selecting redundant columns may result in unnecessary performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CreatedDate_ID]
ON dbo.YourTable
(CreatedDate, ID)
GO
```

Pay attention to the order of the index `(CreatedDate, ID)`. `CreatedDate` is the first column in index. It is very important. So when you will use `WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-30'`, then your query plan will have `index seek`.

And your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
  CreatedDate
, ID from MyTable 
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

try it using Stored Procedure. The stored procedure is ready to go code which is precompiled code take less time to fetch data.

[Sample stored procedure code](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp)